# XAML AppBarButton Hover Colors

Tags: xaml, colors, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing a Universal Windows App in VS2015 (C#, XAML).

I have an AppBarButton on a RelativePanel, The panel's background is black.

When I move the mouse over the button (Hover), it turns black with a darkgray background, which is not visible on a dark background:

[image]

Please tell me how to change the colors for the button in all mouse states: hover, mousedown,...etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom style template for button to overwrite the hover effect and behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Please open the button in Blend by using Edit A copy and then edit its template! you might need to remove some element.

Mostly it shall be a button as the property of changing color is exhibited by a button control